# netStream seek on Android for Adobe Air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, mp4, netstream

I have net stream that plays mp4 files form Amazon S3.

Currently when I call `_ns.seek(time)` if the file is buffered to that point the seek will work, else it will wait until the video is linear buffered to start playing.

How to make the net stream start playing immediately from seek point?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094870/netstream-play-in-the-middle-of-a-video

Comment: @Jacob, I think his/her question basically amounts to: **Can Amazon S3 server be used as a streaming CDN with byte range requests?**. They need to consider Flash does not allow URL range-requests. so [AS3HttpClient](https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient) might help with that.   .

Comment: thx jacob. I found the answer. need to implement rtmp for android